# The data source is of an invalid type. It must be an IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource

Tags: .net, daab

I'm upgrading a .NET 2.0 site that uses Enterprise Library version 2 (DAAB mainly) to .NET version 3.5 and EntLib version 5.  I've made the necessary changes and now I'm getting an error "The data source is of an invalid type.  It must be an IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource".   I'm getting this error trying to set the datasource of a DevExpress ASPxGridView control to an IDataReader.

Below is my code.  Our app uses IDataReaders extensively....will these instances all need to be modified?  I saw one article here that said to add .ToList() to the end of the data source but that is not a valid method in the IDataReader.  Please note that while this particular file is C#, 99% of our app is coded in VB.NET.

```
private void GetRecentAddedCasesGridData()
    {
        dbReader = DAL.GetRecentAddedCases(iClientKey);
        if (dbReader != null)
        {
            GridRecentAddedCases.DataSource = dbReader;
            GridRecentAddedCases.DataBind();         
        }
        dbReader.Close();
        dbReader.Dispose();
        dbReader = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> AsEnumerable(this IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var ret = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        reader.GetValues(ret);
        yield return ret;
    }
}
```

Then you can write
`GridRecentAddedCases.DataSource = dbReader.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Why is this change necessary???  Is it a .NET Framework 3.5 thing?  Is it a DAAB 5 thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "DAAB 5 thing".

According to "ctavares" at CodePlex:

"This was a bug fix. In Entlib 3.0, we added support for System.TransactionScope. It turns out we did it wrong, and caused some intermittent failures in large systems under load. To the point that the bug cost some large companies quite a bit of money in figuring out the problem, and they ended up removing entlib from their system completely. Part of this fix required that we do reference counting on database connections that we own so that we don't close them down until they're no longer used (which was the bug). As such, we needed to wrap data readers so we could properly detect when a reader was closed and manage our connections correctly. The bug was actually posted here on codeplex somewhere, but I forget the work item number.   "

Source: http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/211288